What Causes Program Performance to Decline Despite an Increase in Cache Hit Rate?
I am using the Raspberry Pi 5 to explore the impact of cache prefetching on performance. The Raspberry Pi 5 features a Cortex-A76 CPU with a total of 4 cores, each equipped with L1 and L2 caches (64KB L1 cache per core, 512KB L2 cache per core), and sharing a single L3 cache (2MB).
I am working on a simple case, running a matrix column read program, and aiming to enhance performance by using the ARMv8 PRFM instruction to prefetch target elements. By adjusting various prefetch distances, I observed some performance improvements. However, data collected with perf revealed an issue: while the L2 dcache cache miss count decreased, the access frequency of the L3 cache increased. My understanding is that if a load hits in the cache, it shouldn't access the L3 cache, so this increase in L3 access is puzzling. Another related issue is that although the L2 cache hit rate improved, the overall program performance declined.
The table below shows the cache metrics for different prefetch distances:
table1



prefetch distances
l1d_cache_rd
l1d_cache_wr
l2d_cache_rd
l2d_cache_wr
l3d_cache_rd
cycles
instrctions
time(s)




no prefetch
5801742333
1421583157
72903665
72510120
109592615
16683311907
14390792510
6.437592


1
5978719208
1421205756
72937072
72518228
109916026
13064846101
14425690322
4.826689


2
5978712724
1421327571
72938445
72519305
115868873
13653861469
14424978109
5.255271


3
5978063623
1421179641
72940910
72525954
156868751
18976102863
14424265905
7.529704



table2



prefetch distances
l1d_cache_refill_rd
l1d_cache_refill_wr
l2d_cache_refill_rd
l2d_cache_refill_wr
l3d_cache_refill




no prefetch
71274958
1140772
38356619
0
102573169


1
71269281
1140391
34252836
0
102416664


2
71270464
1140287
30173944
0
103771682


3
71273830
1140920
56143836
0
128838982



The above data represents cache metrics collected through perf stat. I find the following parts reasonable: the read and write counts for the L1D cache (l1d_cache_rd, l1d_cache_wr) in Table 1 are stable, indicating that the number of program accesses and read/write operations on the matrix is fixed. Additionally, the total number of instructions in the program remains stable (with an increase corresponding to the addition of prefetching code).
However, the point of confusion is that, according to the data in Table 2, the number of L2D cache misses(l2d_cache_refill_rd) for 2 prefetch distance is lower than that for 1 prefetch distance . Therefore, one would expect that 2 prefetch distance should perform better than 1 prefetch distance. However, as shown in Table 1, the matrix read time for 1 prefetch distance is 4.8 seconds, while for 2 prefetch distance, it is 5.3 seconds. The cycles consumed by the program also indicate a performance gap between the two. What could be causing this counterintuitive result?
Additionally, I am curious about why, even though the number of L2D cache misses decreases with 2 prefetch distance, the read counts for the L3D cache increase compared to 1 prefetch distance.
The matrix column read program I am using is as follows:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define ROWS 500        
#define COLS 38000        
#define ITERATIONS 30
#define DISTANCE 0

int main() {
    printf("Prefetch Distance : %d\n", DISTANCE);
    int **matrix = (int **)malloc(ROWS * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        matrix[i] = (int *)malloc(COLS * sizeof(int));
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 100;
        }
    }

    int sum = 0;
    clock_t start = clock();
    for (int iter = 0; iter < ITERATIONS; iter++) {
        for (int j = 0; j + 16 < COLS; j+=16) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
                if(i + DISTANCE < ROWS)
                    __asm__ volatile("prfm pldl2strm, [%0]" :: "r"(&matrix[i+DISTANCE][j]));
                for(int t = j; t < j + 16; t++)
                    sum += matrix[i][t];
            }
        }
    }
    clock_t end = clock();

    printf("Sum: %d\n", sum);
    printf("Time taken: %lf seconds\n", (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        free(matrix[i]);
    }
    free(matrix);

    return 0;
}

